# Cocos2d sprite MoveTo a clicked button?

Tags: button, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

Cocos2d newbie here. I am building a game in which I have a sprite and 5 buttons spread out.  I want the sprite to move to the direction of the button I clicked.  I have the following code:

In my init:

```
goHere1=[CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"goToBut.png"selectedImage:@"goToBut.png" target:self selector:@selector(imHere:)];
goHere1.position=ccp(70, 650);
```

Then the method:

```
- (void) imHere:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"I'm Here");
    [mole runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5 position:????????)]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you passed as the selector action for your `CCMenuItemImage` can access which `CCMenuItemImage` it is triggered from using the `sender` method parameter. Therefore you can get the position using `((CCMenuItemImage*)sender).position` (need to cast the `sender` variable to a `CCMenuItemImage` first)

```
- (void) imHere:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"I'm Here");
    [mole runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5 position:((CCMenuItemImage*)sender).position]];
}
```

Comment: I thought of that too but I get the following error: "Property 'position' not found on object of type 'id'"

Comment: This is showing up in Review as Low Quality. Maybe add some explanation, @Lukman?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
-(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
CGPoint touchLocation=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];
touchLocation=[[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
touchLocation=[self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

 self.moveaction=[CCSequence actions:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f position:touchLocation],[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(moveend)],nil];
[sprite runAction:moveaction];
 }
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As I know you shouldn't use `moveTo` method to animate sprite. Didn't you notice that when you use 'moveto' then your move isn't smooth?

I do it this way, maybe not perfect.

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [zoombase convertTouchToNodeSpace:myTouch];
    self.destinationLocation = loaction;
}
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [zoombase convertTouchToNodeSpace:myTouch];
    self.destinationLocation = loaction;
}

-(void)update:(ccTime)dt {

    //that will do until your sprite reach you destination point
    if(!CGPointEqualToPoint(self.spriteToMove,self.destinationLocation)) {
        CGPoint *stepToMove = ccp(0.2/destinationLocation,0.2/destinationLocation); //some piece of orginal destination
        [self.spriteToMove setPosition:ccpAdd(stepToMove,self.spriteToMove.position)]; // add that pice to your sprite current location
    }
}
```